# Combination of two words from a sentence

Tags: r, string

I require to get combination of two words from sentence in R for example
ABC is a string with value as "hello friend how are you"

required O/p is in the form of vector where each element contains two word output like

```
V[1] - "hello friend"
V[2]  - "friend how"
V[3]  -  "how are"
V[4]  -  "are you"
```

I am able to get this using this code. Please suggest if any better way to do this

```
Z = 1
for (l in 1:(length(ABC) - 1)) {
  E[z] <- paste(ABC[l], ABC[l+1])
  z <- z + 1 
}
```

Comment: Could you try `NGramTokenizer` function from `RWeka` package? i.e. run the command `NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))`.

Comment: Thanks. NGramTokenizer works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function using `sapply`:

```
fun <- function(dat,sep) {
    n = unlist(strsplit(dat,split=sep))
    m = length(n)-1
   sapply(1:m,function(x) paste(n[x],n[x+1]))
}

abc <- c("hello friend how are you")

fun(abc," ")
```

If you have a list of phrases you want to split, you can wrap `lapply` around the function:

```
abc <- c("hello friend how are you","test sentence one","test sentence two")

lapply(abc,function(y) fun(y," "))
```